# Accessing data from a folder with a space before its name on hdfs

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I have a directory with path  `/user/xyz/     data` on HDFS
I am unable to access it.

I have tried

```
hdfs dfs -ls  /user/xyz/     data
hdfs dfs -ls  "/user/xyz/     data"
hdfs dfs -ls  "/user/xyz/     *data"
hdfs dfs -ls  "/user/xyz/\     data"
```

None of them are matching.

What could be the best way to access it?

Comment: Try `%20` instead of a space

Comment: what about `hdfs dfs -ls /user/xyz/*data`

Answer (score 0):

To Access the HDFS Use This:

```
hadoop dfs -ls  /user/xyz/
hadoop dfs -ls  /user/xyz/data.txt
```